# Php Mysql Terms

Tags: mysql

I have configured wordpress in local system. I came across these terms in Phpmysql database under wp_options.

Can any one please tell me, what does it mean?

```
a:2:{s:12:"twentyeleven";s:7:"/themes";s:9:"twentyten";s:7:"/themes";}
```

Comment: do a search for php unserializer and paste that in to get the array.

Answer (score 1):

What you just found in your database is the serialized form of an array.

For the sake of understanding the concept, see [the PHP manual on the serialize function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

As an aside: Apart from the fact, that you found this in a WP database though, this question is not WP specific and actually beyond the scope of WPSE.